# node express install without internet

Tags: node.js, express

I have installed node.js & npm on a Redhat server in a closed environment. Now realized that I can't use npm to install anything. I want express, jade and stylus. I have tried looking for packages to download install with npm but no luck. Can I do this without an internet connection on the server?

Thanks,

e

Answer (score 6, accepted):

On another server with internet access and npm run "npm install jade" etc.

Then copy the "node_modules" directory across to the closed server

Also, note that if there are any compiled modules the server architectures should match (And any post build scripts would need to be identified and run manually)